# How to expand widget boundaries in QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt

[image]

I would like to eliminate the border from a QTabWidget as shown in the diagram. The bottom half of the tab labels should occlude the widgets where they intersect. Is this possible? Code follows:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "QGraphicsScene"
#include "QTableWidget"
#include "QGraphicsView"
#include "QTextEdit"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QGraphicsView* left = new QGraphicsView(new QGraphicsScene);
    QTextEdit* right = new QTextEdit;

    QTabWidget* tab = new QTabWidget(this);
    tab->insertTab(0, left, "Left");
    tab->insertTab(1, right, "Right");

    setCentralWidget(tab);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `QWidget::layout()` and `QLayout.setContentsMargins ( int left, int top, int right, int bottom )` methods. For example:

```
ui->centralwidget->layout()->setContentsMargins(9,9,9,9);
tab->layout()->setContentsMargins(9,9,9,9);
```

Should make the change you want. But I'd suggest creating and modifying forms in in Qt designer rather than in code.